# Generating Typescript Typings for third party JQuery Plugins?

Tags: typescript

I was attempting to write a D.TS file for a third party JQuery UI element I found. However, I can't quite seem to wrap my head around it.

After looking at other definition files, they all seem to work for items that are more akin to standalone libraries, but not plugins per-say.

The plugin I'm working with [can be found here](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/#api). But I've yet to find any typings for it. Has anyone worked with something similar?

Comment: While looking for the same, I have found this definition file for the Bootstrap-toggle plugin written by Dani.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768948/type-definition-for-bootstrap-toggle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [definition file](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.d.ts) for the jQuery Transit plugin is a good example of what you're looking for.

For plugins, first the jQuery definition from Definitely Typed should be referenced:

```
/// <reference path="../jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>
```

Then the plugin can be defined on the existing `JQuery` interface. The plugin you linked would look something like this:

```
interface JQueryBootstrapToggleOptions {
    on?: string;
    // [...]
    height?: number;
}

interface JQuery {
    bootstrapToggle(options?: JQueryBootstrapToggleOptions): JQuery;
    bootstrapToggle(method?: "destroy"): JQuery;
    // [...]
    bootstrapToggle(method?: "disable"): JQuery;
    bootstrapToggle(method?: string): JQuery;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick definition file e.g. `bootstrapToggle.d.ts` would containing the following :

```
interface JQuery { 
    bootstrapToggle: any;
}
```