# Type definition for Bootstrap-Toggle

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I was trying to create a type definition file for [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) and ended up having a bootstrap-toggle.d.ts file like this:

```
interface BootstrapToggleOptions {
    on?: string;

    off?: string;

    onstyle?: OnOffStyle;

    offstyle?: OnOffStyle;

    size?: Size;

    width?: number;

    height?: number;
}

type OnOffStyle = "default" | "primary" | "success" | "info" | "warning" | "danger";
type Size = "large" | "normal" | "small" | "mini";

interface JQuery {
    bootstrapToggle(): JQuery;

    bootstrapToggle(options?: BootstrapToggleOptions): JQuery;
}
```

In my angular component I have following code (only parts are shown):

```
@ViewChild('competitionToggle') competitionToggle: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        $(this.competitionToggle.nativeElement).bootstrapToggle({
            on: 'Yes',
            off: 'No'
        });
    }
```

So far so good, webpack transpiles everything without errors.

But when I run it I get this error:

> $(...).bootstrapToggle is not a function

What do I need to change that it works?

I use TypeScript 2.0.6 and Angular 2

Comment: your typings look good to me (and cleared up typescript warnings I was getting) - the error you get must be from angular not importing the library?